# Excel VBA: Validating a cell's value after changing it

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a function that updates a range of cells to a certain value after the user changes one cell to this value. However the cells in this range do not share the same validation range so I would like to do separate validation for each cell updated.

Here's what I have so far. For each cell, the data validation is set to its own validation range with acceptable values. For some reason the validation holds true even though the data is not in the validation range. I'm not too sure how the validation.value property works..

```
For index = 1 to UBound(someArray)
    wksSomeSheet.Cells(index, column).Value = requiredValue
    If Not wksSomeSheet.Cells(index, column).Validation.Value Then
        MsgBox "A value is not supported for one the cells."
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Or should I implement it so that I use the `Range("validationRange").find(requiredValue)` instead?

Comment: I think you are trying to do this? http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/vba-data-validation-and-enforcing-it-to-work/

Comment: Yes thank you, that works. I had to make some alterations because sub was already in worksheet change. Your implementation is similar to that of finding the value inside the validation range.

Comment: I would recommend you to post the final solution and then accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having looked at Siddharth's blog, I made some minimal changes to his code to adapt it to my needs:

```
Dim currentValidation As Excel.Validation
wksSomeSheet.Cells(index, Target.Column).Value = requiredValue

Set currentValidation = wksSomeSheet.Cells(index, Target.Column).Validation
If currentValidation.Type = xlValidateList Then
    Dim validationFound As Boolean, MyArray As Variant
    validationFound = False
    MyArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(Mid(currentValidation.Formula1, 1)))
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        If requiredValue = MyArray(i, 1) Then
            validationFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not validationFound Then
        MsgBox wksSomeSheet.Cells(index, wksSomeSheet.Range("myRange").Column).Value & " does not have a valid value."
        Exit For
    End If
End If
```